# Faster way to iterate between 3 arrays who match values and meet conditions? typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, hashmap, iteration

So i'm having trouble trying to build out an excel sheet faster than 20 seconds. I'm using the below to compare 3 different arrays to then print out the answer i need.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.arrayNumberOne[0].length; i++) {
    let orangeOne = this.arrayNumberOne[0][i]['item_1'];
    let orangeTwo = this.arrayNumberOne[0][i]['item_2'];
    let orangeThree = orangeOne.concat(orangeTwo)

    for (let k = 0; k < this.arrayNumberTwo[0].length; k++) {
        let appleOne = this.arrayNumberTwo[0][k]['item_1'];
        
        for (let j = 0; j < this.arrayNumberThree[0].length; j++) {
            let grapeOne = this.arrayNumberThree[0][j]['item_1'];
            let grapeTwo = this.arrayNumberThree[0][j]['item_2'];
            let grapeThree = this.arrayNumberThree[0][j]['item_3'];
        
            if (orangeThree == grapeOne && appleOne == grapeTwo) {

                if (grapeThree == null || grapeThree == '') {
                    // print to response to excel
                }

                else if (grapeThree == 'sells') {
                    //  print stuff to excel
                }

                else if (grapeThree == 'buys') {
                    // print stuff to excel
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was looking at hashmaps and interfaces, but im not quite sure how i could apply that here. I would appreciate any alternatives to making the above faster.

Edit:

[image: excel output example]

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgGwIYE8CmAnCMC8MDaAUDCTAN4wBEiqmAkgCaUBcVAjAEyUwC+ANMVIVqydBkYsqAZgAs3foJLCaYia0ps5vAaXJUV9JurZT5OoftGHJlDloW7lV8UaoBWe4QC6hQqEiwAJZQaAC22HhEjlTBYQDCSCEA5iAYKDZwIFCB4JR8MSGhAHJIoWg2EKFICAgAtJnZudqKepSxoQnJqenqaACOAK6BcGVgUHkFYSVlFQAWqVC1EADuqUzN0W2FnWgpaRlZOWATW1Ol5eplDIEDofWHTQ4Wpx2Ju902-UMjaGMn7dMLlQkhg0IlakgAB7lDbPdo7PY9fQPY75F6AmzIDBJND3RrHWFKSavLr7XqDYajcZogHnTEDYAAaxQS3maAg8m8vn80BgSGA+IiBBaTloLm4rAA5JxJTTtokMTApQ0jpVqnUVeBZVR+fiJTBJQAjAYoSWE1oGcVKg2ybUvTqKqVfSm-KAQeYYRYrNZ23VHfWSiBoGpmp5EkRiiTW6UyO3whV06OasBXG53ZO+gX+6NBkPm0WqdZSkxx+VQR0G50-MYgsGLKFoTN66Oh8zhy1RqV2UvxBMzJMorE4vFHJvZqWtkWWSNFg0eHskiuSqtUhAM5mskDssdNKXG03NHyEABmAzAWfAMCqgTAAAoAJTkFrH1IwW8INBBXAwAAMAG4YECGAAB5AMKCAADoPzAJIoFmADAgAakQx8yBaXQPyCMtv3aCB8ECLx8EleNSVNHxdAwz8wLOUIcPA-DCOIwpAUlciKJITCYFAUJDRvNBOjo3soAg-xgESW9aVCe9fHYkgXwwN9OMZb9-xgZTQMtSDoNg+C1OQ1D0NkziOwYV1AmPFBv00-BGUYkzWJk2TdHkxSqIAKxUgCPNAv1wC034dK8-SnycpzON8sAAAVnEYb8Irwty7JihgHNCoyqIiugy0BOKL0gfBEqIkiWLYtLKNgCKABUQAAERAXLBQYoiIocwy0vMt9uN4sB+MSXA8Ey7LzhgAAyEb4GSsyLP6vk8uimcDLK0K2qWwDjzfKravqnA8DAAYahgAAfQ7Zvxaq6pmyVJUW1a0oAeju+BMHk2iIpW26SB5EAPygkAklvSUGHqsAslmG8kmu96yp4RyPtIYMgzWja8vO7a8CNE1rpCuHZIep6MBe06jih26vp+hA-oBqoMGUpBsH3SGcdIGGSdChG0CR29NounaDVzBAsbQpn2LxuBntSV68tZpaybQX7-slanaewfnGeFmG4Y16GVq1kgYZZ6873vIA)

Comment: What does this algorithm do exactly, in plain english? Also if you post a self contained example that we could run ourselves and benchmark, that would help a lot.

Comment: It compares from the first array which contains 10 players and then the second array which contains about 657 rows of items they can use. The third array contains the player info and if the player buys the item, sells the item or ignores the item.  ill post an example image of what im currently building

Comment: What does your actual data look like? It's really hard to know what `grapeOne` means and how this fits into your screenshot. Again, if you post a self contained example we can help you much better. For example, something like this https://tsplay.dev/wO8PzN that shows the data going into your function, runs your function. You can stub out the part where you write to excel, as it sounds like that's not the important part here.

Comment: @AlexWayne here is the link, i hope this helps make my question clearer. I appreciate your help Alex!

Comment: happy to help if I can :) But sadly I don't see a link anywhere.

Comment: @AlexWayne haha sorry i was having a bit of a hard time putting the link here.
I added it to my main post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sets off a red flag here is that you have 3 nested loops, but your data is 2D, so you would expect at most 2 nested loops (one for X and one for Y). What you want to focus on is that the process for getting the value of each cell should be as fast as possible, since that is what needs to happens to largest number of times.

The key here is pre-process your values (what goes in the cells of your spreadsheet, buy/sell/blank) in a way that makes it very quick look those up.

For example:

```
// Index all actions by player id and item name
const indexedActions: {
    [playerId: string]: {
        [itemCatName: string]: string
    }
} = {}

// Loop through all actions once to index them.
for (const {playerId, itemCatName, action} of actions) {
    if (!indexedActions[playerId]) indexedActions[playerId] = {}
    indexedActions[playerId][itemCatName] = action
}
```

After that runs you'll have data like:

```
{
    "12": {
        "potionsmall-potion": 'buy'
        // etc...
    }
    // etc...
}
```

That's important because now looking up any cell is as easy as:

```
indexedActions[playerId][itemName]
```

Which lets you completely remove that most inner loop.

```
// Loop through items
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let itemCat = items[i]['itemCategory']
    let itemNam = items[i]['itemName']
    let combineCat = itemCat.concat(itemNam)
    
    // Loop through players
    for (let k = 0; k < players.length; k++) {
        let playerIdentify = players[k]['playerId']
        
        // Lookup what this player did with this item
        const actionToDo = indexedActions[playerIdentify][combineCat]

        // do stuff with action
    }
}
```

### Before Optimization

- for every item

  - for every player

    - for every action

      - doLogic()

Here "doLogic" is executed `itemCount * playerCount * actionCount` times.

### After Optimization

- for every action

  - index each action
- for every item

  - for every player

    - doLogic()

Now we do a little more work up front, but `doLogic` is only executed `itemCount * playerCount` times, which is a huge improvement.

And as a bonus it's less code and easier to read!

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5&ssl=20&ssc=61&pln=20&pc=43#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgGwIYE8CmAnCMC8MDaAUDCTAN4wBEiqmAkgCaUBcVAjAEyUwC+ANMVIVqydBkYsqAZgAs3foJLCaYia0ps5vAaXJUV9JurZT5OoftGHJlDloW7lV8UaoBWe4QC6hQqEiwAJZQaAC22HhEjlTBYQDCSCEA5iAYKDZwIFCB4JR8MSGhAHJIoWg2EKFICAgAtJnZudqKepSxoQnJqenqaACOAK6BcGVgUHkFYSVlFQAWqVC1EADuqUzN0W2FnWgpaRlZOWATW1Ol5eplDIEDofWHTQ4Wpx2Ju902-UMjaGMn7dMLlQkhg0IlakgAB7lDbPdo7PY9fQPY75F6AmzIDBJND3RrHWFKSavLr7XqDYajcZogHnTEDYAAaxQS3maAg8m8vgQaFgSGA+IiBBaTloLm4rAA5JxJTTtokMTApQ0jpVqnUVeBZVR+fiJTBJQAjAYoSWE1oGcVKg2ybUvTqKqVfSm-KAQeYYRYrNZ23VHfWSiBoGpmp5EkRiiTW6UyO3whV06OasBXG53ZO+gX+6NBkPm0WqdZSkxx+VQR0G50-MYgsGLKFoTN66Oh8zhy1RqV2UvxBMzJMorE4vFHJvZqWtkWWSNFg0eHskiuSqtUhAM5mskDssdNKXG03NHyEAD0x5gcVBbxgSBgUHAMBAADMYAxEkgAHSfwh+8BC-Cf98f0gfIAKAiAQM-MCIMArNf2gqCYFA2DgMQyDkPA1CYMFI9HwGMBkJgKpAjAAAKABKchfF0U8YDoMAGDQSFrxqa90JgQ0UHgZwYECBhr3onjChgMBzhafxoB4+jGLQBgAEF0NYMgWl0fAOwYVhoAwYiki8RTlN0Uh8Hjctzg0qAtLAHSzIspJ9JIHgWh4XByAcloaIAGRAEA4FvWYMBAAYklmZiEFYwUH3wtBbxASSGKYqBZjCd8WkfVIYBI8TYDINT8mMwF8iApynzC1UKKUgzSECZ8SIAQmIuKZPkwVVOcRgvAo+rpLk9CWpnLxnLIByKpITroW65q1K8Iyy0Bfq8CAxyqNIDyvJ8hL-MC4L2ggFK0pInkgmcgAGABuHiYAAHkEsIIHfHlLISs7AgAamesq7JgA7rpJZztqMqbJWM940klHxhs+3lvumX7Cggf78EBwpAVBj6vtAUJDWItBOhh3soHffxgESEjaVCMiPo+lbvN8jagq4sUdvB1KMHSr7GWOs72auy1bvupJHpgRlXve8HdC+tTXSqzi8B5-BGQBtSUdF0gPuos9PJARkBh85ZZkSXzAmwS0X14mBlmCYKEsN77VdITKSvAAAVEAABEYrwUbGp6iWxilqb0cxsBscSI9lZG6qgOdt3cDwMABhYgAfBOHbAKP3bwSVJRFsO1fgTBmdCFPbYq8SQB5O6QCSEjJQYGKwCyWZtKz4veCW5XgyDHiI+QtOY4Nfcs8onPc7gfPUkLhbh7t38y7QCuq8lKoMHZpBsAH8mc9cnOO6iqr0sj1304NXMEEH8qp5gGjR4wAui4vmBS-LhBK+rpeV+wE-m83j6htIBzXPttAJAnpnLXwLkgSK7567LHIoQIipFyaPzns-KuYDx4QOAHPaB5EYC1BgEAz0+RF4QCzkAA)

Comment: Sorry for the late response Alex but this was defiantly what I was looking for! I was able to adapt it to my project and it worked perfectly ! i brought down the time it took to draft my data from 20.2 seconds to less than a second !